# IE7 horizontal bar keeps going forever

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a horizontal bar that appears on a list page when you add more panels via ASP.Net which is bigger than the website width of 928px.

This works well in all browsers apart from *drumrolls* - IE7

In IE7 the bar starts looking fine but as you slide the bar across it just keeps going, like it is accommidating for a page that is 4000px + wide rather then say 1200px.

Here is the CSS for the inner DIV:

```
#topholder
{   
    width: 928px; 
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    xpadding-left: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: hidden; 

    /* IE 7 hack */
    *position: relative;
}
```

and the outer div:

```
#panelMain {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The basic ASP panel is layed out like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/dQ6FM/

Comment: HTML & CSS in a JSfiddle please

Comment: Two thoughts:
 1 - position:relative is causing the element to stay on-screen.  Try removing that?  Or changing to position:static;
 2 - overflow:hidden instead of overflow-y:hidden

Comment: Thank you @Joshua, if I change the position in any way/remove it it causes it to error. Also I cannot have a overflow:hidden as I need the scrollbar if there are too many panels to display on the page that is 928px wide.

Comment: @Paulie_D I understand that would be very helpful but I am not allowed, however I have updated the question with the basic frame.

Comment: How can you be not allowed to make a basic JSfiddle...does not compute.

Comment: @Paulie_D here is the fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/dQ6FM/

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails... try hiding the rest of the page?

```
html {overflow-x: hidden;}
#topholder {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Comment: Thank you for this Joshua, but this removes the bar completely. The problem lies within how large the bar itself is. For example the page is 928px wide on a list page and I add two more columns which makes it 1024px wide, the horizontal bar would appear but its like the bar thinks it should accommodate for about 4000px

Comment: And overflow-x:hidden for only the containing element yields the same result?  Hmm... I'll keep poking around.  IE7, you dog!

Comment: /* IE 7 hack */
    *position: relative;  Maybe try *position: fixdd, static, or absolute?